# How to save .py files in VSCode on linux and write the admin password only once?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on Linux Sabayon (Gnome) and when I want to save any `.py` files I have to write the admin password for each one. Is there some settings that may fix it?

I know that I can run Visual Studio Code  as admin but that's not the best option for me.

Comment: are you the admin?

Comment: Yes, i am the admin

Comment: You shouldn't be doing anything as admin. Why do you need to save them as admin at all?

Comment: It might be the directory you are saving them in. I recommend making a folder on your desktop and saving them there. (I am not that good with linux but I know that it's similar to windows)

Comment: Because when i want save them as normal i get error saying:"Failed to save 'views.py': Insufficient permissions. Select 'Retry as Admin' to retry as administrator." so then i have to save them as admin ... the folder is located in Documents

Comment: @TomášKubát where are you saving them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the saved file in a folder on your desktop.

Saving files in non-user directories (directories that don't refer to YOUR user) may need admin permissions.

This method should work on **ALL** PC platforms.